# EF Core FindAsync returns only root object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a many to many relation and I am using ASP.Net Core2.2 MVC with EF.

From what I read I understand that at the current time I have to create a CLR class for join table.

My code:

**Models:**

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        Categories= new List<PostCategory>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<PostCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
  {
      public Category()
      {
          Posts= new List<PostCategory>();
      }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public ICollection<PostCategory> Posts { get; set; }
    }
public class PostCategory
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**DBContext:**

```
 public class MyDBContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
    {

    }
    public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.CategoryId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Post)
            .WithMany(m => m.Categories)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PostId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Category)
            .WithMany(e => e.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

Create Post Code:

```
var categories= new List<PostCategory>();
foreach (var category in model.SelectedCategories)
 {
  categories.Add(new PostCategory()
   {
      CategoryId= category
    });
 }
model.Post.Categories.AddRange(categories);
_context.Post.Add(model.Post);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When I create a post I can see in database that I have Post data, and in PostCategory table I can see PostId CategoryId as they should be.

My issue is when I try to get a post data using:

```
var post = await _context.Post.FindAsync(id);
```

post.Categories count is always 0, what am I missing?

Comment: Does making the properties `Categories` and `Posts` as `virtual` give the same results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your query as follows to eager load the related `Categories` with `Post`:

```
var post =  await _context.Post.Include(p => p.Categories).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

Here is the more details about [Loading Related Data in EF core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will work but may not be as performant - when using FindAsync if the entity is already being tracked you'll get that copy rather than going to the database

In order to have that and load related data you need to do it manually

for example:

```
context.Entry(post)
    .Reference(p => p.Categories)
    .Load();
```

references:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit#explicit-loading
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.findasync?view=efcore-7.0#overloads